# Divisibility of sum of three powers times two powers

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, exponential-diophantine-equations

I am trying to find some restrictions for what the exponents, $a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, of two powers can be if the following equation yields an odd integer:

$[3^{n}+3^{(n-1)}2^{(a_{2})}+3^{(n-2)}2^{(a_{2}+a_{3})}+...+3^{(1)}2^{(a_{2}+..+a_{n-1})}+3^{(0)}2^{(a_{2}+..+a_{n-1}+a_{n})}]/[2^{(a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n})}-3^{n}] = m$

Where $n\geq1$, $m\in2\mathbb{Z}+1$, and $a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}, a_{i}>0$

What divisibility rules can I use to place restrictions on what values $a_{i}$ can take?

Written in another form:
$3^{n}+3^{(n-1)}2^{(a_{2})}+3^{(n-2)}2^{(a_{2}+a_{3})}+...+3^{(1)}2^{(a_{2}+..+a_{n-1})}+3^{(0)}2^{(a_{2}+..+a_{n-1}+a_{n})}=m(2^{(a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n})}-3^{n})$

Comment: Your formula seems to be inconsistent. You start out with $3^{n-1} 2^{a_2}$ and $3^{n-2} 2^{a_2+a_3}$ (note $n-1 + 2 = n+1$ and $n-2 + 3 = n+1$) but end with $3^{1} 2^{a_2 + \ldots + a_{n-1}}$ and $3^0 2^{a_2 + \ldots + a_n}$ (note $1 + n-1 = n$ and $0 + n = n$).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The exponents on 3 will be {n,n-1,n-2,...,2,1,0} and the corresponding exponents for 2 will be {0,a_2, a_2+a_3,..., a_2+...+a_n-2, a_2+...+a_n-2+a_n-1, a_2+...+a_n-2+a_n-1+a_n}